# Django - How to use filter with exclude well?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models

I can't figure out the way to build a query, so I need some help here! This is the models:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, primary_key=True)

class Service(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)

    views = models.ManyToManyField(Employee)
```

So, an employee need to get the first service that does not have an assigned employee, the query would be the following:

```py
Services.objects.filter(employee__isnull=True)[:1]
```

An employee can see a service only once, after the employee see the service is added to `views` in `Service` model like `service.views.add(employee)`. Because the query is made for employees, I need to exclude the services that the employee has already seen before, I tried something like that:

```py
Services.objects.filter(employee__isnull=True).exclude(views__views__employee_id=1)[:1]
```

How should I do it? Thanks.

Comment: It should be `views_id` or `views__id` since views field is your employee in this case.

Comment: your employee table should have the same fields as the user (for now). The service is the many-to-many table that connects them for an assignment. You can then look which user does not appear in the service table. I would add datetime fields for the assignment table ( assigned, started, finished). Then you can check under the not unfinished assignments which employee does not have an assignment, that has started. So you could even reassign employees, if they haven't started yet, but the customer is highly important.  no

Comment: But I would add a field to the user, as to whether they are waiting for the service. That way you keep all users past interactions (in the assignment table) and all users from past service.